# installing ruby enterprise edition - older version

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-enterprise-edition

I have some legacy code that needs to run on REE 1.8.7-2010.02 patched version. But I see that `rvm install ree-1.8.7-2010.02` doesn't work anymore cuz wget fails. Is there a workaround to install this version at all? Any url still open for downloading this version?

Answer (score 1):

`REE 1.8.7-2010.02` was built on top of 1.8.7. It contained improvements at memory level, but the external API were the same of Ruby 1.8.7.

I believe you can easily install 1.8.7, if you just need to run and test the app.

I would not use 1.8.7 in production anymore, regardless it's REE or standard Ruby.